# Cannot seem to create a new label :/ in relation to my menu function - is there any better way to structure my code or fix?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, label

```
from tkinter import *

class Employee:
    """Create an employee"""
    def __init__(self, forename, surname):
        self.forename = forename
        self.surname = surname
        self.username = forename[0] + '.' + surname
        self.employeeID = 1
    def employeeUsername(self):
        """Generates a username using the forename and surname of the employee class"""
        return "{}".format(self.username)

root = Tk()

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master) # confused.

        self.frame = Frame(master)

        self.lu = Label(self,text = "Username: ",fg ="black",bg="white",font=("Courier",13))
        self.lp = Label(self,text = "Password: ",fg ="black",bg="white",font=("Courier",13))

        self.eu = Entry(self)
        self.ep = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.lu.grid(row = 0, sticky = E)
        self.lp.grid(row = 1, sticky = E)
        self.eu.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.ep.grid(row = 1,  column = 1)

        self.log = Button(self,text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.log.grid(columnspan = 2)

        self.pack()

    def menu(self):
        print("Y")

        self.ml = Label(self, text = "Option Menu", fg = "black", bg = "white", font = ("Courier",13))

        self.pack(side = TOP , fill = X)

    def login(self):
        '''Login page'''
        uname = self.eu.get()
        pword = self.ep.get()
        if len(uname) < 5 or len(pword) == 0:
            self.error = Label(self,text="Incorrect Password",fg ="black",bg="white",font=("Courier",10))
            self.error.grid(row = 3 ,column = 1)

        else:
            root.destroy()
            self.menu()

            print("X")



main = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your Question needs more explanations

Comment: When I run my code , I get an error saying I label cannot be created and application has been destroyed

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show a [mcve] with full **Traceback**

Comment: You can't create a new Label because you destroy the root window. Why do you think you should use `root.destroy()`?

Comment: I planned to use root.destory to destroy the login window and then open a new window for the menu , seems like a bit of logic problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot errors in your code.

If you destroy the root window you will destroy also all other widgets.
Therefore you can't use your self.menu methode anymore.

You are using different geometry managers it would be better when you are using just one.

You pack wrong widget in your self.menu methode it should be self.ml.pack() and not self.pack()

Your Gui constructor use super() without passing self

```
from tkinter import *

class Employee:
    """Create an employee"""
    def __init__(self, forename, surname):
        self.forename = forename
        self.surname = surname
        self.username = forename[0] + '.' + surname
        self.employeeID = 1
    def employeeUsername(self):
        """Generates a username using the forename and surname of the employee class"""
        return "{}".format(self.username)

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master) #still confused?
        self.pack()    
        #self.frame = Frame(master)  it's pointless variable
        self.lu = Label(self,text = "Username: ",fg ="black",bg="white",font=("Courier",13))
        self.lp = Label(self,text = "Password: ",fg ="black",bg="white",font=("Courier",13))
        self.eu = Entry(self)
        self.ep = Entry(self, show="*")
        self.lu.grid(row = 0, sticky = E)
        self.lp.grid(row = 1, sticky = E)
        self.eu.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.ep.grid(row = 1,  column = 1)
        self.log = Button(self,text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.log.grid(columnspan = 2)

    def menu(self):
        print("Y")
        self.my_label = Label(self.master, text="Option Menu", fg="black", bg="white") #font=("Courier",13)
        self.my_label.pack(side = TOP , fill = X)

    def login(self):
        '''Login page'''
        uname = self.eu.get()
        pword = self.ep.get()
        if len(uname) < 5 or len(pword) == 0:
            self.error = Label(self,text="Incorrect Password",fg ="black",bg="white",font=("Courier",10))
            self.error.grid(row = 3 ,column = 1)
        else:
            #root.destroy()
            self.menu()
            #or use self.menu2() for creating toplevel window
            print("X")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It would be better when you do create a Toplevel window and put your self.my_label in it.

like:

```
    def menu2(self):
        self.my_toplevel = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.my_label = Label(self.my_toplevel, text="Option Menu", fg="black", bg="white") #font=("Courier",13)
        self.my_label.pack(side = TOP , fill = X)
```